# Fixing a recursive python program that crashes after processing

Tags: python, recursion

I need some help with some homework. I am not that familiar with python. However, I have some problem with this small python program. It uses recursion to print out a set of number based on the function given. It gets to about num = 30 and the program crashes. Not sure what is wrong or how to fix it. help?

```
def func(num):
  if num==0:
   return 0
 elif num==1:
   return 1
 else:
   return func(num-1)+2*func(num-2)
for num in range(2,101):
 print(num,func(num))
```

Comment: Probably a `StackOverflowError`? Each function call has to allocate a new stack, so you're probably using a lot of resources upon each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't crash but the number of recursion becomes big and it takes too long to calculate, you can use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to speed things up in recursion by passing a dictionary to store the values that were already calculated and then you can easily retrieve it from the dictionary instead of calculating again. You also don't need to use `elif/else` when if you are returning a value inside your `if-statement`, for example:

```
def func(num, m):
    if num == 0:
        return 0
    if num == 1:
        return 1
    if num not in m:
        m[num] = func(num-1, m)+2*func(num-2, m)
    return m[num]

m = {}
for num in range(2,101):    
    print(num,func(num, m))
```

Comment: Can't you just use `functools.lru_cache`?

Comment: @Zizouz212 OP didn't mention python version, `functools.lru_cache` is not available in python 2 afaik

Comment: I just figured because of the `print` function. But you're right, it's only in Python 3.

Comment: Why are you clearing `m` on each loop iteration? BTW, it'd be faster to do `if num not in m` rather than `try...except KeyError` since the exception gets raised fairly frequently.

Comment: Wouldn't make much difference in the OP's case, but you're right once the number gets larger it will be more efficient to move `m` outside the loop and check `if num not in m` instead of `try/except`.  Edited, thanks